# grails dependency resolution

Tags: java, maven-2, grails, groovy, ivy

My Grails project depends on an intenal library `Commons.jar` which is built with Maven. In `BuildConfig.groovy` I have configured it to look for this dependency first in the local Maven repository, then in the company-wide repository.

```
repositories {        
    // Read the location of the local Maven repository from $M2_REPO
    mavenLocal System.getenv("M2_REPO")        
    mavenRepo "http://build.mycompany.com/wtp_repository"
}

plugins {
    build 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:1.0.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile ('com.mycompany:Commons:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
}
```

When I build Common/jar (using `mvn deploy`), it is stored first in mavenLocal, then copied to mavenRepo. However, when I build the Grails app, it looks for the JAR in the following locations:

- Ivy cache (defaults to ~/.ivy2/cache)
- mavenLocal (defined by $M2_REPO)
- mavenRepo (http://build.mycompany.com/wtp_repository)

So the Grails app is constantly picking up an old version of the JAR from the Ivy cache, which is never updated when the Commons project is built.

I guess I could fix this problem if I knew how to:

- Prevent Grails for looking for dependencies in the Ivy cache (though I guess disabling the cache might slow down my builds considerably)
- Ensure that the Ivy cache is also updated when I build Commons

However, it seems that anyone else that references SNAPSHOT artifacts of Maven projects should also have this problem, so perhaps I'm missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I guess [this discussion](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/ivy-snapshot-dependencies-not-updating-in-grails-td3048669.html) is related to the problem you have and possibly suggests some workaround/solution.

Comment: Please consider adding relevant sections of the linked information to your answer to help combat link-rot and to make this answer useful on it's own.